# Reusing footer html code

Tags: javascript, html, css

Since the footer is repeated throughout the web pages I have, I have moved the footer to a separate file named footer.html.
In my footer, the copyright year is updated dynamically using javascript.
I have managed to load the footer.html file into my page but the since the year keeps reloading itself. How can I load the footer.html file and update the year in the same script file. I have added my code in jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/wpbmn0z2/

***footer.html***

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted"><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
        <p class="text-muted"> Copyright &copy; abc <span id="yearfooter"></span>.</p>
    </div>
</footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

***css***

```
.footer {
     bottom: 0;
     height: 60px;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     text-align:center;
     background-color:#FFFFFF;
 }

.footer > .container {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}
```

***javascript***

```
$(function(){
 $("#footer").load("footer.html");
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#yearfooter').text(new Date().getFullYear());
});
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine. Have you included `jQuery`?

Comment: I dont see any issue in your code. But in the jsfiddle you didnt included jquery. Please check this modified jsfiddlehttps://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/wpbmn0z2/1/

Comment: If you meant to add the year in the same call as load, then you can look at the `callback` provided for `load`

Comment: @SandeepNayak Yes, I have included jQuery into my footer.html.

Comment: It seems to work just fine https://jsfiddle.net/wpbmn0z2/7/

Comment: I have the same thing as yours, but its not showing the year in mine https://jsfiddle.net/wpbmn0z2/

Comment: Jquery isn't running in your Fiddle. Click on the cog icon in the javascript code area to add it.

Comment: @SandeepNayak how can I make use of the callback method? https://jsfiddle.net/wpbmn0z2/ would that be a right way to go bout it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it working the way I want it to. The following is the javascript code

```
$(function(){
    $("#footer").load("footer.html", function () {
        $('#yearfooter').text(new Date().getFullYear());
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix your problem ? Load the footer and update the year when the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#footer").load("footer.html");
     var year = new Date().getFullYear();
     $('#yearfooter').text(year);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your bracket is in problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#yearfooter').text((new Date).getFullYear());
});
```